# Capture image from a scanner

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-scanner

I am developing a small application to get some picture from a scanner.
What is the best option (free) to get the picture from the scanner?
Already tryed with the WIA, but always gives me this error  HRESULT: 0x80210015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx).